# can i use an if statement to append to a string?

Tags: java

Right now I have the following code, and I'm trying to get the code to append to a string instead of system.out.println. I know this is worded oddly, but not sure how to put it.

```
char[] c = inputString.toCharArray();
     for(char ch : c) 
     {
         if(ch <=88 && ch>=65 || ch<=120 && ch>=97) 
         System.out.print(Character.valueOf((char) (ch+2)));

         else
            if (ch =< 1)
                System.out.print(Character.valueOf((char) (ch-24)));
            else 
                if (ch == 2)
                    System.out.print(Character.valueOf((char) (ch-24)));
                else
            System.out.print(ch);
```

Comment: Yes, of course, just replace your System.out.println with the relevant code.

Comment: It's really unclear what you're trying to achieve here. We don't know what you're trying to append to what, for example. (I'd also *strongly* advise using braces on all if statements.)

Comment: I'd like to have String result = (Character.valueOf((char) (ch-24))); , and i will add the braces

Comment: More a side note: if you end up doing a lot of appending to the same string consider using a `StringBuilder`. It's faster and uses less memory (since each time you append to a string you create a new instance of that string).

Comment: `String result = (Character.valueOf((char) (ch-24)));` - you probably want `String result = String.valueOf((char)(ch-24));` instead.

Comment: can i use StringBuilder to append it in the if statement? i need it to go through the loop and change each character and append it to a string

Comment: I'd recommend using the char literals instead of int values, e.g. `'A'` instead of `65`.

Comment: I'm getting a error (string cannot be resolved to variable) for String result = String.valueOf((char)(ch-24));

Answer (score 3):

all you need is defining a string next to your `c[] array`and add those characters to it by this operator `+=` and at the end you have a complete string of what you want, so

```
char[] c = inputString.toCharArray();
String str = "";
for(char ch : c) 
{
     if(ch <=88 && ch>=65 || ch<=120 && ch>=97) {
        str += Character.valueOf((char) (ch+2));
     } else{
        if (ch =< 1){
            str += Character.valueOf((char) (ch-24));
        }else {
            if (ch == 2){
                str += Character.valueOf((char) (ch-24));
            }else{
                str += ch;
            }
        }
     }
}

// now str is the result that you want an you can do any operation on it as you wish
```

Answer (score 0):

Your could also use StringBuffer as below:

```
char[] c = inputString.toCharArray();
StringBuffer strBf = new StringBuffer();
String str;
for(char ch : c){
    if(ch <=88 && ch>=65 || ch<=120 && ch>=97) {
       strBf.append(Character.valueOf((char) (ch+2)));
    } else{
       if (ch =< 1){
           strBf.append(Character.valueOf((char) (ch-24)));
       }else {
           if (ch == 2){
              strBf.append(Character.valueOf((char) (ch-24)));
           }else{
              strBf.append(ch);
           }
       }
   }
}
str = strBf.toString();
```